# How to load a website in my webapplication like iframe, I need an alternative to <iframe>? 

Tags: asp.net, html, iframe

I need to load an eBook in my HTML page. EBook is of flash, pdf, normal html or any.

Apple safari doesn't support with `<iframes>`; so I need an alternative for iframeset.

Comment: Safari **does** support iframes.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of loading in frameset, I suggest you can use jQuery dialog box, it will be more fancier, and will support all browsers.

[Jquery Pop up Dialog box](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/)